# How to download dll from maven repo in runtime?

Tags: java, maven, dll, dependency-management, aether

I use `eclipse-aether` for downloading jars in runtime, but now I need to download dll from maven. I tried a lot different things but failed. One of them

```
  DefaultArtifact defaultArtifact = new DefaultArtifact(
        "com.tagtraum",
        "ffsampledsp",
        "dll",
        "0.9.29"
    ); 
    Dependency dependency = new Dependency(defaultArtifact, "runtime", false, Set.of());
    CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest().setRoot(dependency).addRepository(remote);
    DependencyNode root = repoSystem.collectDependencies(
        newSession(repoSystem, new File("./"), new CancellableTransferListener(new DownloadState("test"))),
        collectRequest
    ).getRoot();
```

What do I wrong? How I can resolve my problem ?

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: @f1sh I don't have any message. This code works, but it downloads just pom file